# Violin graph in r

Tags: r, violin-plot

I am trying to write a script that plots violin plot without explicitly describing the levels of the plot. lets say: `x1=c(x11,x22,....,x1n), x2=c(x21,x22,...,x2m), ... xp=(xl1,....,xlj)`. If I had the number of levels in advance I could have enterend: `violin(x1,x2,...,xp)`. However, I can't (the number of levels (p) is defined is a variable). I am tried to put it in `datastrucre (x=list(x1,x2,...xp)` and than do `violin(x)`. But it did not work. is there someway else to put the vector in some data structure that could be passed to `violin()`.
Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is nor what package `violin()` is from. Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: That said, `ggplot2`'s `geom_violin()` might be worth looking at.

Comment: Are your variables in a useful structure like a list? Because `do.call(what = violin, args = list_of_x)` seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Gregor gave the answer:
do.call(what = vioplot, args = x)